# Getting a bound on solution of PDE in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $$\varphi(s) = \begin{cases}
s &: s < 0\\
0 &: s \in [0,1]\\
s-1 &: s > 1
\end{cases}$$
Note that $\varphi$ is Lipschitz. Consider where $f \in L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega)$,
$$u_t - \Delta (\varphi(u)) = f \text{ in $\Omega \times (0,T)$}$$
$$u|_{\partial\Omega} =0$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
Apparently if I take $\varphi(u)$ as a test function, I can obtain an estimate on $u$ in $L^\infty(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$, but I can't see this. Can someone help me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\varphi$ is just Lipschitz, second order weak derivatives of $\varphi(u)$
may not exist no matter how smooth be a solution $u$. That is why
$u$ is to be treated only as a weak solution. So, let $u\in H^1\bigl(\Omega
\times (0,T))\bigr)$ be a weak solution of the problem, *i.e.*, 
let $u$ possessing traces $u|_{t=0}=u_0$ and $u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$ 
satisfy the integral identity
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}u_t v\,dx+\int\limits_{\Omega}\nabla\varphi(u)\cdot
\nabla v\,dx=\int\limits_{\Omega}fv\,dx \quad \forall\, v\in 
H^1\bigl(\Omega\times (0,T))\bigr)\colon\,v|_{\partial\Omega}=0
$$
*a.e.* on $(0,T)$. The required bound follows by a routine trick of
introducing a function $\Phi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\Phi'=\varphi$
where
$$
\Phi(s)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{s^2}{2}, &s<0,\\
0, &s\in [0,1],\\
\frac{(s-1)^2}{2}, &s>1.
\end{cases}\tag{$\ast$}
$$
Notice that $\varphi^2(s)=2\Phi(s)\leqslant s^2\;\forall\,s\in\mathbb{R}$. 
Choosing a test function $v=\varphi(u)$ yields
$$
\frac{d\,}{dt}\int\limits_{\Omega}\Phi(u)\,dx+\int\limits_{\Omega}|\nabla\varphi(u)|^2dx
=\int\limits_{\Omega}f\varphi(u)\,dx
$$
*a.e.* on $(0,T)$, whence by the Cauchy–Bunyakovski inequality follows 
$$
\frac{d\,}{dt}\int\limits_{\Omega}\Phi(u)\,dx\leqslant \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
\|\varphi(u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\biggl(2\int\limits_{\Omega}
\Phi(u)\,dx\biggr)^{1/2}
$$
*a.e.* on $(0,T)$, implying the bound
$$
\biggl(2\int\limits_{\Omega}\Phi\bigl(u(x,t)\bigr)\,dx\biggr)^{1/2}\leqslant
\int\limits_0^T\|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}dt+\|u_0\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
*a.e.* on $(0,T)$. The rest is easy due to the definition $(\ast)$ of function $\Phi$.

**Remark.** At points $x,t$ where $0\leqslant u(x,t)\leqslant 1$ solution's 
smoothness *w.r.t.* $x$ is not generally to be expected higher than that of a solution
$u(x,t)\overset{\rm def}{=}\psi(x)$ with some $L^2(\Omega)$ function $\psi\,\colon 
\Omega\to [0,1]$ vanishing near the boundary $\partial\Omega$ and possessing no weak 
derivatives, which solves the problem corresponding to $f=0$ and $u_0=\psi$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let me forget $f$. Then, notice that
$$
\int u_t\phi(u)=-\int (\nabla \phi(u))^2,
$$
where we used the boundary conditions and the definition of $\phi$ to remove the boundary term
$$
\int_{\partial\Omega}\phi(u)\nabla\phi(u)nds=0.
$$
Now
$$
\int u_t\phi(u)=\int u_t u\textbf{1}_{u<0}+\int u_t (u-1)\textbf{1}_{u>1}=\int u_t u\textbf{1}_{u<0}+\int u_t u\textbf{1}_{u>1}-\int u_t \textbf{1}_{u>1}.
$$
Now
$$
0.5\frac{d}{dt}|u|_{L^2}=\int uu_tdx=\left(\int uu_t\textbf{1}_{u>1}+\int uu_t\textbf{1}_{0\leq u\leq 1}+\int uu_t\textbf{1}_{u>1}\right).
$$
So
$$
0.5\frac{d}{dt}|u|_{L^2}=\int u_t\phi(u)+\int u_t\textbf{1}_{u>1}+\int uu_t\textbf{1}_{0\leq u\leq 1},
$$
$$
0.5\frac{d}{dt}|u|_{L^2}=-\int (\nabla \phi(u))^2+\int u_t\textbf{1}_{u>1}+\int uu_t\textbf{1}_{0\leq u\leq 1}.
$$
Now, if $u>1$, $u_t=\Delta (u-1)=\Delta u$, so 
$$
\int u_t\textbf{1}_{u>1}=0.
$$
On the other hand, if $|u|<1,$ $\partial_t u=0$. Putting all together we conclude, right? Is that correct?